# Submit button not working in form - laravel

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

Here I used laravel 5.6. In my project I appended a form using ajax by rendering form. But here submit form not working. When I press submit button it does not make any action.  It is acting like

my ajax code is

```
 $.ajax({
       url:"/add-form-content",
       type: 'GET',
       data: {

             },
      success: function (response) {
             $('#cat_C_EEL_content').empty();
             $('#cat_C_EEL_content').append(response);
           }
      })
```

blade

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" action="{{ url('set-reward') }}" method="POST" >
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="category_name" value="C-EEL">
                <select name="reward" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="gold">gold</option>
                    <option value="silver">silver</option>
                    <option value="bronze">bronze</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            </td>
        </form>
```

Comment: You need to inspect your event listeners on the submit event and tell us what's that ajax code is supposed to do ? how is it related to the form you provided ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I loaded form using ajax. But not submit it in ajax. I also Inspected elements. Form content is there. I am confused why it is not submitting. It is acting like <input type="button"

Comment: If you Inspect Element in the browser, are the {} gone in the html?

Comment: I did not get your point. Are u mentioning action="{{ url('set-reward') }}" this ? It replaced with action="http://localhost:8000/set-reward"

Comment: Please don't describe thing like it's not working. Do you get anything errors from console? do you have router corresponding to your form submit? You need to edit your question to make it clear. You ajax code seems like has nothing to do with your issue.